# How to display several RTSP streams at once?

Tags: video, rtsp

I want to be able to show several RTSP live streams simultaneously. Like, the phone screen divided in, say, 4 parts and in each part a separate stream from a separate IP camera displayed.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, your question as is, is considered off-topic by our [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), as it falls under "Can you suggest an app that does X?". Consider rephrasing it to prevent it to get closed.

Comment: I have edited the question to ask for a solution rather than an app recommendation.

Comment: @Al Everett Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted to ask. I'm sorry, not being a native English speaker, couldn't rephrase myself better

Answer (score 1):

Hm, 4 parts from different cameras -- looks like [IP Cam Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rcreations.ipcamviewer) is capable of that:

[image: IP Cam Viewer]

Not that hard to find: Just entered "ipcam" in the search box at the playstore site, and clicked on the first result. You might want to [try the others](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ipcam&c=apps), maybe you find something even better suited for your requirements. Or use [this one](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ipcam+%2Brtsp&c=apps) to better restrict it (ipcam + rtsp).

Comment: I've tried that but can't get it working with my Axis rtsp camera... I have P5512 Axis camera

Comment: I don't have any IP camera, so I cannot test. Did you follow the other links, and check some of the other offered solutions? The latter search had only a one-page result set, so it shouldn't take that long. You could also check [this overview](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/410039/) (German -- but just Ctrl-F and check for "dvr", from there you can use the app links. And there's always [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpit.de%2Fde%2Fandroid%2Fforum%2Fthread%2F410039%2F)).

Comment: Looks, that program doesn't support RTSP

Comment: @Alex Sure? App description in playstore says: *RTSP, h.264, MPEG4 support*